# How do I find a vein of my custom ore?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have written a mod to produce a new ore which is working great. Then I added some more code so that veins of this ore would be randomly generated. I cannot tell if this is working as I cannot find any veins.

Is there a way to locate a vein of my ore in vanilla Minecraft?

Comment: why don't you just make the "generation" code at just above ground level, to see if it works. Then generate "normally"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an XY problem and the real Y (how do I test whether my mod that generates ore is working) is off-topic as gamedev.

Answer (score 16):

One possible testing solution could be to edit your texture file and turn everything except for your new ore transparent. Then whenever you want to see where the ore has been placed, change skins back and forth between the transparent one and the original.

This solution isn't directly vanilla, but it is at least within the bounds if vanilla by just being a texture pack.

Comment: This is really smart, and editing the texture file is really quick and easy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't reveal ores that are buried unless they touch air.  (Though I have seen it work for blocks that touch air)

Comment: Also in upcoming versions, blocks that are not visible will not be rendered, meaning that transparent X-Ray texture packs will be useless.

Comment: @DavidWilkins I didn't know this. That makes sense though. Should make the game run more efficiently as well

Comment: @davidwilkins does that mean that the massive land pop-in during initial world generation will be gone too? I haven't played in a while. It's unfortunate that X-ray textures will stop working, but I guess it's for the best in terms of balance.

Comment: @zero298 You can see for yourself in the latest snapshots...Its still being worked on, but you will see lava rivers if your computer is slow.  It is not fit for public consumption just yet, so I cannot say how much the slow chunkloading will improve

Answer (score 8):

The simplest and most reliable way is to simply print each ore vein's coordinates to the console when it's generated, so you merely have to enter creative mode and teleport yourself to one of the veins. This way, you'll get *every single* vein reliably and just by adding a single line of code to the ore generation.

Answer (score 3):

Just make the ore generate 1000 times per chunk! That's what I did. I then changed it back to 10 times per chunk for the actual mod release (it's in beta testing with my friends right now). If it spawns 1000 times a chunk, it'll be really easy to find.